How do I allow an account to assume a role in a different account in AWS CDK?
I have a role in account B that grants access to certain services and allows account A to assume it, but I'm not sure how to actually make account A assume the role.
I set the roles up like so:
cross_account_role_arn = (
    "<role_arn>"
)

assume_role_policy = iam.PolicyStatement(
    actions=["sts:AssumeRole"], resources=[cross_account_role_arn]
)

cross_account_role = iam.Role.from_role_arn(
    self, "CrossAccountRole", role_arn=cross_account_role_arn
)

But I don't know what to actually attach the role to, since it's the CF User itself that needs the access to the resource.
Here's the error it results in for more context:
API: certificatemanager:changeResourceRecordSets User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/cdk-asdsfghjjkkl-cfn-exec-role-123456789-us-east-1/AWSCloudFormation is not authorized to access this resource


How exactly did you set up your pipelines? E.g., do you have a CodeBuild (might be part of a CodePipeline) in account A, which should create resources in account B using cdk? You need to bootstrap cdk in account B and add account A as trusted account (flags --trust  --trust-for-lookup ) . After that, you need to assume the lookup or deploy role from account B.
CDK Pipeline is probably also useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html

@ChristianBanfi No I simply have a stack of resources in CDK and deploy it when changes are made, no specific pipelines set up.

@ChristianBanfi What I specifically don't know is how to assume the role from account B in account A.

you either have to explicitly assume the role with your user from account B (see aws sts assume-role) or configuring an environment in your cdk stack (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/configure-env.html).
